# Can I delay the interpretation of CURRENT_SCHEMA if used in a Snowflake view?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Because the concept of current user, current database, etc is so important and a bit confusing in snowflake, I tried to come up with a view that would help our developers/users.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW AUDIT.WHO_AM_I_VIEW
AS
   SELECT CURRENT_USER() AS CURRENT_USER
        , CURRENT_ROLE() AS CURRENT_ROLE 
        , CURRENT_SECONDARY_ROLES() AS CURRENT_SECONDARY_ROLES
        , CURRENT_WAREHOUSE() AS CURRENT_WAREHOUSE
        , CURRENT_DATABASE() AS CURRENT_DATABASE
        , CURRENT_SCHEMA() AS CURRENT_SCHEMA
        , SPLIT_PART(CURRENT_DATABASE, '_', 1) AS ENVIRONMENT
        , CURRENT_SESSION() AS CURRENT_SESSION
        , SYSDATE() AS CURRENT_TIME_UTC;
```

Unfortunately, some of these functions seem interpreted at view creation time rather than runtime.

For instance, in this example, the view will always return "AUDIT" as the current schema, regardless of the current schema in your session...
Same for the database...

:-(

Is there any way, CURRENT_DATABASE(), CURRENT_SCHEMA() could return my session database rather than the database where the view was created?

Thanks

Comment: I think this is either a bug or the SF documentation for these functions is incorrect/unclear. I think this is something you need to raise with Snowflake Support to get clarity on how it the functions are meant to work